# TFS no release folder in build folder

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a tfs build that works fine on the client, but when executed on the server, no actual binaries get created.

When I go to the folder: \[MyServer]\builds[BuildName], I see 
BuildLog.txt
ErrorsWarningsLog.txt
Release.txt

I expect to see a big 
\Release 
folder full of my dlls, but I get nothing.

The error log reports no problems up until we ask the build to copy the binaries to our staging server.  If I comment those out, I get no errors.

CustomizableOutDir  is true,
DropLocation is set to something sensible
BuildDirectoryPath is set to something sensible

But no matter what, I just don't get any dlls built.  Our local TFS guy is baffled too.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If CustomizableOurDir is true, the build output should be in each project's bin\Release folder (you can check by looking under the Source folder on the build machine working directory).

You need to add an manual copy step to then copy each bin\Release folder to the $(Binaries) folder.